# Safari — window 'x' not attached to window 'y'

Tags: safari, macos, kernel-panic

Since macOS 10.12.1 update, there's unresponsivenesss in Safari especially with JS.
First noticed this error when using hotkey <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to Show/Hide Reading List.
Unlike before, Safari is force closing on a daily basis.  
Ive had this occur in **Safari** && **Safari Technology Preview**[image]
I thought this was directly related to the Sidebar, however console renders an error each time I swipe to go back or forward.

### So far I have tried:

- Repair Disk from Recovery Mode
- Reset SMC
- Reset PRAM
- Internet Recovery

**Update/Edit:** I finally was able to reproduce the Kernel Panic, however it happened while I was afk.

```
Anonymous UUID:       3585841F-F73B-6F23-560E-5F850C1BD2F6

Thu Nov 10 17:21:15 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80094065ea): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800910e14b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff921a3d9000, CR3: 0x000000000dfb4000, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000c16, RCX: 0x0000000000000be0, RDX: 0xffffff802b7acd00
RSP: 0xffffff91ff3238c8, RBP: 0xffffff91ff323940, RSI: 0x0000000000006900, RDI: 0xffffff921a3d9000
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x0000000000000004, R10: 0xffffff91ff3236f8, R11: 0xffffff802d62e870
R12: 0xffffff802d62e000, R13: 0x0000000000000004, R14: 0xffffff921a3d8600, R15: 0x0000000000000002
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff800910e14b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff921a3d9000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91ff323550 : 0xffffff80092f368c 
0xffffff91ff3235d0 : 0xffffff80094065ea 
0xffffff91ff3237b0 : 0xffffff80092a5743 
0xffffff91ff3237d0 : 0xffffff800910e14b 
0xffffff91ff323940 : 0xffffff7f8a757bf1 
0xffffff91ff323970 : 0xffffff7f8cd7da10 
0xffffff91ff323a30 : 0xffffff7f8cd7dd28 
0xffffff91ff323a60 : 0xffffff7f8cd7d3a4 
0xffffff91ff323aa0 : 0xffffff7f8cd7d013 
0xffffff91ff323ae0 : 0xffffff7f8cd762f5 
0xffffff91ff323c70 : 0xffffff7f8cd76ce7 
0xffffff91ff323e00 : 0xffffff7f8a7592db 
0xffffff91ff323e40 : 0xffffff7f8a758476 
0xffffff91ff323e80 : 0xffffff7f8a754373 
0xffffff91ff323ee0 : 0xffffff80098be1ff 
0xffffff91ff323f30 : 0xffffff80098bca61 
0xffffff91ff323f80 : 0xffffff80098bc046 
0xffffff91ff323fb0 : 0xffffff80092a2af7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f8a749000->0xffffff7f8a783fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C29002A1-DF76-3A8E-8D67-D70922DF86AE]@0xffffff7f89b32000
         com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer(1.4.6)[4CAE0594-133E-31E6-8F7A-DA3A935DCC03]@0xffffff7f8cd6d000->0xffffff7f8cd91fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f8a0c1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C29002A1-DF76-3A8E-8D67-D70922DF86AE]@0xffffff7f89b32000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(1.4.6)[F44047C9-7E55-3B22-AB72-FC07B8E812ED]@0xffffff7f8c289000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f8a749000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: -s

Mac OS version:
16B2555

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Thu Oct 13 21:26:57 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.3~60/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 8941AC1C-B084-37DE-8A34-4CE638C5CFC9
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009100000
System model name: iMac17,1 (Mac-DB15BD556843C820)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 72981338561679
last loaded kext at 72979690945653: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8d680000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 65401683816176: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8d680000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 103
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 103
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   278.23
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.23
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.1f7
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1110.4.1a8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   5.0.1f7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.23
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.6
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.15
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.20.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: iMac17,1, BootROM IM171.0105.B09, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.33f10
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M390, AMD Radeon R9 M390, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314739453220
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314739453220
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x14A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST1000DM003, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 28.1
```

### Processes that were running:

- Terminal ($ top -o cpu)
- Safari (1 window)

Comment: Can you please post your kernel panic log, and tell us when you get kernel panics? (While using safari?)

Comment: @IronCraftMan I've included kernel panic log however,  I was not next to my computer when it had to shut down.